# Docker AWS ECR push failure from command line

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to follow the guideline supplied in the ECR page of Amazon. I've created a repository according to the documentations. I've created a local image and applied tag to it as said online.
I've configured aws using the command: aws configure.

After all that when I try to execute

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <My ID>.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
```

I receive the following error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidSignatureException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

An error occurred (InvalidSignatureException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that the region configured when running:

```
aws configure
```

and the region configured in the get-login-password wasn't the same region

Comment: According to the error the issue was that your access key and secret key did not match. Wrong region won't cause an authentication error.

Comment: Also specifying `--region` on the CLI overrides whatever you have set as the default region in your local config.

Comment: @jordanm, I'm new to aws so maybe you're right, though I can say for sure that after changing the region to match it started to work. I did not do any other actions